Keyboard backlight doesn’t work on kubuntu 24.04
I am using a Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 3 with Kubuntu 24.04 installed. This laptop provides two brightness levels for the keyboard backlight, but I am only able to toggle the first brightness level using Fn + Space. Could someone help me fix this issue so that I can toggle between both keyboard backlight brightness levels?
Thank you in advance.
